# android - Dialog with transparent background (with any color)

Tags: android

[image: I want to do following]I want blue translucent behind custome dialog box. but I am not getting blue color

Here is code of dialog declaration:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BookAppointmentActivity.this,R.style.TranslucentBlue );
                //Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BookAppointmentActivity.this,  android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen );

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customedialog);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));


                dialog.show();
```

Here is my style.xml

```
<color name="transparent_green_color">@color/dialog_back</color>
    <style name="TranslucentBlue" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_green_color</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got the solution

First make change in theme.
Don't make custome theme. Use `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BookAppointmentActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

instead of custom theme, and add following:

```
window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.dialog_back);
```

Full code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customedialog);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();

window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.dialog_back);
dialog.show();
```

Use color from your resource file `color.xml` and at last but not least don't forget to decrease the opacity of the color.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!